# Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44395' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, post, cors, fetch, asp.net-core-webapi

I have **Asp .net core 3** web API. I am calling one of the POST API using Fetch then getting the following errors:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44395/api/challengeresponse/Verify' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

So I research and try following in Web API code:

> Startup.cs

```
private readonly string AllowedOriginPolicy = "_AllowedOriginPolicy";
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(AllowedOriginPolicy,
                    builder =>
                    {
                        var corsOrigins = new String[1] { "https://localhost:44395" };

                        builder.WithOrigins(corsOrigins).AllowCredentials().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
            });

            services.AddControllers();
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   app.UseCors(AllowedOriginPolicy); //at the end of the method.
}
```

Still, I am getting the same errors.

My Fetch code is:

> sample.js

```
async function fetchdata(){
    let _data = {
        OriginalData: "coordinateid",
        Signature: "URL",
        Certificate: "introduction"
    }

    const response = await fetch('https://localhost:44395/api/challengeresponse/Verify', {
     credentials: 'include',
     method: "POST",
     body: JSON.stringify(_data),
     headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
})
.then(response => response.json()) 
.then(json => console.log(json))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

It is a very common question but still, I am not able to solve. Please help.

Edit: Please suggest for `http://` and `https://` both type of URL's. Because I also deployed this web API on the main server, and accessing from server URL also gives the same error.

Comment: `origin null` suggests the page making the request is not served using http[s]

Comment: Is your javascript file being run from an html page also being hosted by a local server? You'll encounter some trouble if you just open the file from your browser locally

Comment: Yes, javascript file is run from HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This url `https://localhost:44395` in

> var corsOrigins = new String[1] { "https://localhost:44395" };

It should the client's url . It should be changed to be like this:

```
var corsOrigins = new String[1] { "[client url]" };
```

Note: No matter what client you use, please make sure it runs on a server.

Comment: after this change, also did the same change in `fetchdata()` URL. Now getting an error:  `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: @Varsh, the error means that the url could not find the server. What client do you use?

Comment: I am not getting exactly what are you asking as I am not very much handy to this. But, I run my web API project, after that calling its POST API from plain javascript file which gets calls from HTML page on Chrome browser.

Comment: @Varsh, how do you run this javascript, open it directly? What is your client address?

Comment: Open HTML file with the browser. The address is `file:///D:/Varsha/Project/main.html`

Comment: @Varsh, this way of opening it is not correct. You can put it on a server, then access this html through an address, such as: http://127.0.0.1:8080/main.html

Comment: Okay, according to my next step. I deployed this web API on the server (company's main server). Who's URL is `http://***:***/api/challengeresponse/Verify` .And calling this URL from fetch. In this case what should be the `var corsOrigins= new String[1] { url }` URL?

Comment: @Varsh, you need to put the main.html on a server.

Comment: But if the web API is already deployed on a specific server, It should get accessed from anywhere if the COR policy is set. Am I Incorrect?

Comment: Yes, but now if you do not want to deploy the web api, you need to put the client on a server. Do you have visual sudio code or any other code editor to develop client?

Comment: I have already deployed it on the server (url starting from http://). And want to access it from there. (localhost is just for testing)

Comment: Can you show your client url now? Because you have put the client on a server.

Comment: `http://serveripaddress/server/index.php/login?user= ` this kind of url is there.

Comment: Can you put the `main.html` in `serveripaddress`? Then access the html with `http://serveripaddress/main.html`, and change the url in webapi: `var corsOrigins = new String[1] { "http://serveripaddress" };`

Comment: so basically `var corsOrigins = new String[1] { "http://serveripaddress" };` need the client url from which we are calling API?

Comment: Yes, this url is client url's address.

Comment: Okay, thank you, Sir. The problem gets solved when I change the `var corsOrigins = new String[1] { "http://serveripaddress" };`.

Comment: And one more question, if I want to allow any client without providing a specific URL. Then?

Comment: You can use this method `builder.AllowAnyOrigin()` in webapi, it will allow any client.